# Contdition load of UI elements

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, retina-display

I am trying to customize UI appearance of my app. I used following code, whcih works fine on non iPhone5 and successors (and non retina display), It appears great on simulator.
but on my iPhone5 its not loading the images.

```
-(void)customizeAppearance
{
    UIImage* blueBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menubar.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:blueBG forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UIImage* blueBack = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:blueBack forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UIImage* blueTabBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-active.png"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:blueTabBG];
```

How can I make this conditional load of resource like

```
if(___IPHONE5ORLATER)
 load retina images
else
 load non retina images
```

Comment: you should use the image naming conventions instead; your _Bible_ is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use this type of condition for load retina images,

Put two images

1. `menubar.png` (non retina) (e.g 30 X 30 px)
2. `menubar@2x.png` (retina image) (e.g 60 X 60 px)

Now you simple use

`UIImage* blueBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menubar"];`

iOS will automatically load retina image if device is retina.